# How to avoid nested for-each loops?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've got a class which should parse an XML file, like this:

```
<customers>
        ...
        <customer>
            <id>123456</id>
            <name>Mike</name>
            <orders>
                ...
                <order>
                    <id>233658</id>
                    <positions>
                        ...
                        <position>
                            <id>12345</id>
                            <price>10.0</price>
                            <count>5</count>
                        </position>
                        ...
                    </positions>
                </order>
                ...
            </orders>
        </customer>
<customers>
```

I'm going to unmarshall it with JAXB and than process result objects to get  statistics (like max order amount, total orders amount etc)

Is this a bad practice to use 3-level foreach loop in this case?

```
public void getStatistics() {
    for (Customer customer: this.customers.getCustomer()) {

        BigDecimal customerTotalAmount = new BigDecimal(0);
        for (Order order : customer.getOrders().getOrder()) {

            BigDecimal orderAmount = new BigDecimal(0);
            for (Position position : order.getPositions().getPosition()) {
                orderAmount = orderAmount.add( position.getPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(position.getCount())) );
            }

            customerTotalAmount = customerTotalAmount.add(orderAmount);
            this.totalOrders++;
        }

        this.totalAmount = this.totalAmount.add(customerTotalAmount);
    }
}
```

Customer, Order and Position classes has been generated automatically from XSD schema, and i think it is not good to change them.

What am i doing wrong? How can i avoid those nested loops?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd imagine there should be some libraries out there which would allow you to select elements within the DOM. I've never done this in Java, though, so couldn't point you to any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend extracting some methods:

```
public void getStatistics() {
    for (Customer customer: this.customers.getCustomer()) {
        BigDecimal customerTotalAmount = processCustomer(customer);
        this.totalAmount = this.totalAmount.add(customerTotalAmount);
    }
}

private void processCustomer(Customer customer){
    BigDecimal customerTotalAmount = new BigDecimal(0);
    for (Order order : customer.getOrders().getOrder()) {
        BigDecimal orderAmount = new BigDecimal(0);
        for (Position position : order.getPositions().getPosition()) {
            orderAmount = orderAmount.add( position.getPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(position.getCount())) );
        }

        customerTotalAmount = customerTotalAmount.add(orderAmount);
        this.totalOrders++;
    }
    return customerTotalAmount;
}
```

Do the same thing for the Order and Position loop, give the methods descriptive-enough names and make sure they return proper values, and you get a nice, clean code. These are still nested loops, but at least your eyes don't hurt when you see them.